# JavaScript quickSort wrong output

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

This is the quicksort algorithm I wrote:

```js
var arr = [0, 2, 5, 10, 3, 22, 12, 8, 20];

let quickSort = (arr) => {
  let len = arr.length;

  if (len === 1) {
    return arr;
  };

  let pivot = arr.length - 1;

  const rightArr = [];
  const leftArr = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < len - 1; i++) {
    let j = i + 1;
    if (arr[j] > arr[pivot]) {
      rightArr.push(arr[j]);
    } else {
      leftArr.push(arr[j]);
    };
  };
  if (leftArr.length > 0 && rightArr.length > 0) {
    return [...quickSort(leftArr), pivot, ...quickSort(rightArr)];
  } else if (leftArr.length > 0 && rightArr.length <= 0) {
    return [...quickSort(leftArr), pivot];
  } else {
    return [pivot, ...quickSort(rightArr)];
  };
};

console.log(quickSort(arr));
```

The output is: `[20, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 22]`

My question is: why do I get the wrong output and how do I fix this ?

Comment: The `for` loop skips `arr[0]`.

Comment: fwiw, quicksort is supposed to sort an array **in place**. The posted function creates new sub-arrays by copying into new arrays, which real quicksort does not do.

Comment: There is much wrong with this code, but the problem arises from adding `pivot` to the list instead of `arr[pivot]`, pivot being the index

Comment: thank you @Vulwsztyn i solved the problem and evreything work just fine.

Comment: Since I apparently resolved your issue I added my comment as answer. Would you mind accepting it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is much wrong with this code, but the problem arises from adding `pivo`t to the list instead of `arr[pivot]`, `pivot` being the index

Comment: e.g.: all conditions at the end of code are redundant, why would you use semicolon in js? it's not real in-situ quicksort, for that you should be swaping elements of the array and not create additional ones